# Xero Webhook not receiving events despite ITR status being OK

Tags: node.js, webhooks, xero-api

Good Day to all. I am trying out the Xero webhook in a local setup.

Environment:

- Node js backend
- Using Ngrok for hosting the endpoint publicly
- Xero Trial Account

I was able to successfully set up the webhook. My service received 3 unauthorized (401) calls and 1 successful (200) call, which made the ITR status OK.

However, after the ITR success, I tried creating a contact, updating an existing contact and updating an invoice and waited for nearly 10 to 15 minutes and I did not receive any events to the webhook endpoint.

Not sure if I have missed any steps? Any pointers to why I am not receiving the events?

Is there any way I can see if the events that are fired from the Xero side?
Does the webhook work only for Partner apps?

Not sure what I am missing here. Appreciate any help on this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that your Trial organisation is connected to the app? If not, following the Postman tutorial will ensure that it is connected.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/tools/postman